# FFMPEG Command to scale: How to do this?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg command line in Android and I used the code from ffmpeg.org given as

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'" output_320x240_boxed.png
```

But when I execute it in my phone, I get "error when evaluating the expression. Might be self referencing" for the if part. I want to scale to even numbers of heights and widths as

```
scale=if(iw%2!=0)iw+1:if(ih%2!=0)ih+1
```

but that gives me the same error. What should I change it to? I couldn't copy the console output since it was in a textview. Here are the screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA2D3.jpg

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from your command(s).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Sorry for the late reply. Here's the console output: Unknown function in "'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)' Invalid chars '"" at the end of the expression 'if(gt(a,4/3)-1,240)'". Error while evaluating the expression 'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'". Maybe the expression for out_w:"'if(gt(a,4/3),320,-1)' or for out_h:'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,240)'" is self-referencing. Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_scale_0 Error opening filters!

Comment: Please include the **complete** console output. You can add it to your question instead of trying to cram it all into a comment.

Comment: The application I'm trying it on shows it in a textview. So I've uploaded the screenshots of it in the order. I wish I could have copied it somehow. Could you look into these images and see where I've gone wrong? Though I've used the same command as given in ffmpeg.org. The images are  in this link http://imgur.com/a/Fe3H7

Comment: The command that you show in the question appears to be different than the one in the screenshots: `-1)':'if` vs `-1)'×'if`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Sorry for the late reply again. I've uploaded the screenshots of the output for ":" instead of "x". Please suggest me on how to correct it.